# how to capture connection event in my webSocket server with Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket

I did a simple web socket communication with spring 4,STOMP and sock.js, following this https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio and this
http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html

well, I want to know if is possible capture connection events like when a new client was connected to my server or when a client was disconnected, is that possible in Spring 4.0.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This an be done with a connection handshake interceptor ([HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/server/support/HttpSessionHandshakeInterceptor.html)), quoting the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html):

> The easiest way to customize the initial HTTP WebSocket handshake
>   request is through a HandshakeInterceptor, which exposes "before" and
>   "after" the handshake methods.

Comment: thanks!! well actually I use, a WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer, but using this it works: registry.addEndpoint("/api/v1/ws/pushService").withSockJS().setInterceptors(wsSessionInterceptor);

Answer (score 30):

Spring WebSocket publishes events when messages are received from the client, if you are using STOMP, these are the events published:

- [SessionConnectedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionConnectedEvent.html)
- [SessionConnectEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionConnectEvent.html)
- [SessionDisconnectEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionDisconnectEvent.html)
- [SessionSubscribeEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionSubscribeEvent.html)
- [SessionUnsubscribeEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionUnsubscribeEvent.html)

The easiest way to detect connects and disconnects is by implementing an event listener for the mentioned events.

```
@Component
public class WebSocketEventListener {

    @EventListener
    private void handleSessionConnected(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        ...
    }

    @EventListener
    private void handleSessionDisconnect(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here's a sample implementation that keeps track of connected users: https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sergialmar/wschat/event/PresenceEventListener.java

Comment: Where do you store sessionId?

Answer (score 6):

As I understand, the question with DISCONNECT event is not solved in this topic. Handshake interception gives you only connect info but not disconnect.

I have achieved this with the interceptors of inbound channel:

```
<websocket:message-broker>
    ...
    <websocket:client-inbound-channel>
        <websocket:interceptors>
            <bean class="com......MyChannelInterception"></bean>
        </websocket:interceptors>
    </websocket:client-inbound-channel>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

...and class...

```
import java.security.Principal;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageType;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptorAdapter;

public class MyChannelInterception extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(WrcChannelInterception.class);

@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

    MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
    SimpMessageType type = (SimpMessageType) headers.get("simpMessageType");
    String simpSessionId = (String) headers.get("simpSessionId");

    if (type == SimpMessageType.CONNECT) {
        Principal principal = (Principal) headers.get("simpUser");
        LOGGER.debug("WsSession " + simpSessionId + " is connected for user " + principal.getName());
    } else if (type == SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT) {
        LOGGER.debug("WsSession " + simpSessionId + " is disconnected");
    }
    return message;
}
}
```

Please note that Principal is available on CONNECT but not on DISCONNECT, however you have sweet Session ID

Comment: how could I get the Principal by sessionID?

Comment: @disorderdev on Connect, you can store in your DB the link between sessionId and Principal and on Disconnect, to retrieve the Principal by Session ID

Comment: How do we identify which client along with endpoint client is disconnected ?

Answer (score 0):

Although original question is about Spring 4 - which is well answered by Sergi. Here is a way to do it in Spring 5 or Spring Boot 2 (which uses Spring 5 under the hood). ApplicationListener needs to be implemented:

```
@Component
public class WebSocketEventListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionConnectEvent> {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketEventListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        logger.error("SessionConnectEvent = " + event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet may help you:

```
@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
    logger.info("afterConnectionEstablished called");
}
```