# Spring websocket: how intercept the send event through the AbstractSubProtocolEvent hierarchy?

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

About Spring websocket about intercept `Stomp` events one approach is extends from the [ChannelInterceptorAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/support/ChannelInterceptorAdapter.html) class

It works how is expected. More details here:

- [Spring websocket: how convert easily the Message's payload to POJO in ChannelInterceptorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419131/spring-websocket-how-convert-easily-the-messages-payload-to-pojo-in-channel)

Now, according with this tutorial:

- [Detecting WebSocket Connects and Disconnects in Spring 4](http://www.sergialmar.com/2014/03/detect-websocket-connects-and-disconnects-in-spring-4/)

the approach mentioned above is covered *and* other approach is work around with `ApplicationEvents`, it through with:

- [SessionConnectEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionConnectEvent.html)
- [SessionConnectedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionConnectedEvent.html)
- [SessionDisconnectEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionDisconnectEvent.html)

These classes extends from:

- [AbstractSubProtocolEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/AbstractSubProtocolEvent.html)

And exists two subclasses more:

- [SessionSubscribeEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionSubscribeEvent.html)
- [SessionUnsubscribeEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SessionUnsubscribeEvent.html)

This list is confirmed in (by the same author):

- [how to capture connection event in my webSocket server with Spring 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781667/how-to-capture-connection-event-in-my-websocket-server-with-spring-4/49754626#49754626)

The names are by themselves obvious to know what each one does, but just curious

- Why there is no none for the `send` event?

It to react from:

```
stompClient.send('/app/ws/something', 
                 {}, 
                 JSON.stringify({'content': $('#content').val()})
```

For this `send` event "seems" mandatory work with the `ChannelInterceptorAdapter` through the `postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent)` method yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events reflect *major* points in the lifecycle of a STOMP connection. They're not meant to be notifications for every message sent from the client. For that you can use `@MessageMapping` methods, or a `ChannelInterceptor`.

Comment: Rossen using the ChannelInterceptor with preSend method is the only way to intercept a send event? Is there any filter or something like this?